# What are some approaches to improve the classification of ONE particular instance of interest?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, predictive-modeling, model-evaluations

I'd like to know if there are some methods to correct a specific misclassified instance of interest (e.g. in a Logistic Regression or Random Forest).

Like maybe increasing the error for that particular observation or some other approach.

Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at boosting.

Comment: I'm familiar with that but is it possible to boost one particular instance?

Comment: No. You can use class weight in case of classification (if you want to go down that road).

Comment: Random Forest and Logistic Regression objectives are very different. With logistic regression, you can adapt the objective for what you are looking for. Not in Random Forest which is entropy based

Comment: I see. So other than that are there no other known methods to correct one misclassified instance?